# Using EntityFramework: Context per Presenter or long conversation pattern for Windows Forms Applications?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-4, mvp, unit-of-work

For now I did not use MVP and I tried the long conversation pattern like this:

```
private void SaveItem(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var transaction = _businessTransactionFactory.Create())
    {
        var currentMobileDevice = GetCurrentMobileDevice();

        if (currentMobileDevice.Id == Guid.Empty)
        {
            transaction.MobileDeviceRepository.Save(currentMobileDevice);
        }
        else
        {
            transaction.MobileDeviceRepository.Update(currentMobileDevice);
        }

        transaction.Commit();
        LoadData(transaction);
    }
}

private MobileDevice GetCurrentMobileDevice()
{
    return (MobileDevice)MobileDevicesBindingNavigator.BindingSource.Current;
}
```

Problems I encountered:

- I am always have to work with detached entities.
- Working with detached entites forces EntityFramework to update ALL columns instead of those that changes:

  ```
  public void Update(T entity)
  {
      if (_objectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
      {
          _objectSet.Attach(entity);
          _objectContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entity, EntityState.Modified);
      }
  }
  ```

How do you handle the context in a windows forms application?

What are **pros** and **cons** of both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical scenario is new context per presenter where presenter can handle more than one view in case of different views on the same data. There is very [nice article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819139.aspx) about this in MSDN magazine. It targets NHibernate's session but EF's context management should follow the same approach to solve exactly the problems you are encountering with detached entities.

Comment: Where are the repositories? Has Nhibernate/EF to be referenced by the UI, it seems so?

Comment: Repository is just another design pattern to separate data access implementation from upper layers. EF must be referenced by the code using it. If you access EF directly from presenter (without any wrapper) and presenter is in UI library, the UI library must reference EF.

Comment: Do you know any alternative solutions for the EntityFramework?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff714955.aspx
This shows you one approach to use the repository and unit of work pattern with EF.Instead of using the unitofwork implementation directly in your presenter, make an constructor injection of IUnitOfWork with an IoC container like castle.windsor. besides a clean and scalable architecture you will have a one very nice benefit: castle.windsor offers you (as the most IoC frameworks do) lifetime options for the registered components for example singleton or transient. so it takes you just one line of code to change the lifetime for all presenters implementing the IUnitOfWork. you would be able to initiate each presenter with an seperate instance of unitofwork or with the same instance.

do you need a code sample? by the way, i'm working on an open source github sample for implementing EF in a scalable architecture in a clean manner. i talked to Scott Allen from the ADO.NET Team. He will parcitipate.

Kind regards,
Uli

Comment: I do not like the unit of work mentioned in your link at all. It will cluttering up with each new repository. Furthermore it violates a lots of the SOLID principles. I keep the unit of work seperated from the repositories. I decided me for the approach to use one context per form/presenter.